# Pandas DF Select Column Contained By String

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to figure out the inverse of df[df['A'].str.contains("hello")].  I would like to return all rows from from column 'A' if they have a string in "hello".

If the values were "he", "llo" "l" in column 'A' they would return true.

If the values were "het", "lil", "elp" in column 'A' they would return false.

Is there a way to do this in a dataframe without iterating each row in the dataframe?

Currently using 2.7 due to working with ESRI ArcGIS 10.4 software constraints.

Comment: basically if it contains any of the letters in the string `'hello'`?

Comment: updated to maybe help clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` of Pandas to iterate over each row of column A, and evaluate if it is a substring of 'hello'

```
def hello_check(row):
    return (row in 'hello')

df['contains_hello'] = df['A'].apply(hello_check)
```

Comment: Just `return row in 'hello'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's more concise, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Any idea why .isin doesn't work on a string because I was trying that too.  Strings and lists are essentially the same thing for a lot of things.  Just don't want to use .apply if I don't have to.

Comment: If you are talking about panda.DataFrame's isin(), it is to check if each value in the column is one of the item in the specified list of values, which doesn't seem to be working here. Feel free to share the code you attempt to do in the comment https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html